# How to solve this limit: $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin(x\sin(2x))}{x^2}$

Tags: calculus, limits

How to solve this limit?

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin(x\sin(2x))}{x^2}$$

I tried to solve with trigonometric formulas but no result yet. It seems that need to use this $$ \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin(x)}{x} $$

Comment: Seems like L' Hopital Rule works here.

Comment: In case you are not aware that $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x}{x}=1$, then check [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/75130/how-to-prove-that-lim-limits-x-to0-frac-sin-xx-1?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

$$\frac{\sin(x\sin 2x)}{x^2} = \frac{\sin (x\sin 2x)}{x\sin 2x} \times \frac{\sin 2x}{x} \to 1\times \frac{\sin 2x}{2x} \times 2 \to 1\times 1\times 2 =2 $$

Comment: Is this a common trick? To me this is amazing, +1!

Comment: @Student1058 I think this trick is probably the most common one in evaluating limits involving sines.

Comment: I see. I'll keep that in mind.

Comment: Note that this depends on the fact that both $x$ and $\sin x$ are $\neq 0$ as $x \to 0$.

Comment: Just pointing it out to OP. :)

Answer (score 0):

Since $\sin t=t+o(t)$, you have
$$
x\sin2x=2x^2+o(x^2)
$$
and therefore
$$
\sin(x\sin2x)=2x^2+o(x^2)
$$
so your limit becomes
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{2x^2+o(x^2)}{x^2}=2
$$